# How to get JSON nested object

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I'm using Retrofit, and I want to get this type of object in Android. Can any one explain how can I get? I can get successfully a single simple object, but when it is inside an object, I'm getting response body null.

Here is the JSON

```
{
  "success": {
     "token": "djhfeieryueyjsdheirydjalbbvcxgdgfhjdgs",
     "name": "abc"         
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would depend on the return value you have selected from the retrofit call.

For example, converting that response to a POJO the POJO would be

```
    -----------------------------------com.example.Example.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Example {

@SerializedName("success")
@Expose
private Success success;

public Success getSuccess() {
return success;
}

public void setSuccess(Success success) {
this.success = success;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Success.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Success {

@SerializedName("token")
@Expose
private String token;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;

public String getToken() {
return token;
}

public void setToken(String token) {
this.token = token;
}

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

}
```

So your network call would be

`@POST("api") Call<Example> Login(@Body LoginRequest loginRequest);`

To access this it would look like (pseudo)

```
public static void login(String uname, String pword) {
    Call<Example> getDataResponseSingle = retroInterface.Login(new LoginRequest(uname, pword));

getDataResponseSingle.enqueue()
        new Call<Example>() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Example dataResponse) {
                dataResponse.getSuccess().getToken;
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

    }
```

You can also look at: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to create you own POJO

I you are returning directly a `JSON Object` e.g  `Call<JSONObject> getDataResponseSingle = retroInterface.Login(new LoginRequest(uname, pword));`

Where you see the successful response you access the inner class (pseudo)

```
JSONObject main = response.body();
JSONObject success = main.getJSONObject("success");
```